# Convert data based on multiple dictionaries

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary

I have a data matrix (106 rows and 57 columns), where all the data is `['a','c','g','t']`, and 1 dictionary per column too. What I need to do is apply a transformation for each column based on its own dictionary.

I tried something like this, but the results are not correct.

```
result = []
for x in range(data.shape[0]):
    individual_map = np.empty(data.shape[1], dtype=int)

    for y in range(data.shape[1]):
        for key, val in mapping[y].items():
            individual_map[data[x,y] == key] = val

    result.append(individual_map)
```

Thanks.

EDIT: The sample data has 3 columns only, so I just have 3 dictionaries. In the real case, there are 57 columns and 57 dictionaries.
Sample data:

```
data = [['a','c','g'],['t','g','c']]
dictionaries = [{'a':1,'c':2,'g':3,'t':4},{'a':3,'c':1,'g':2,'t':4},{'a':2,'c':3,'g':4,'t':1}]
result = [[1,1,4],[4,2,3]]
```

Comment: can you show a sample of your data and your dictionaries? what do you get and what do you expect?

Comment: i suppose data is not a list but a numpy.array (otherwise it has no shape)

Comment: You're right. I forgot to mention that. But I'm not getting any type of error, the result is the only thing wrong.

Comment: general advice: consider pandas for such kind of tasks. pandas introducing dataframe which is very useful data structure for many tasks. I think pandas solution will be better to understand after few month pass away...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have,

```
data = [['a','c','g'],['t','g','c']]
dictionaries = [{'a':1,'c':2,'g':3,'t':4},{'a':3,'c':1,'g':2,'t':4},{'a':2,'c':3,'g':4,'t':1}]
```

and the expected result is

```
result = [[1,1,4],[4,2,3]]
```

you can get it with two nested list comprehensions (https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html):

```
result = [[dictionaries[j][item] for j, item in enumerate(row)] for row in data]
```

Comment: Worked really fine! I'm still a beginner with Python, so it's incredible this was done with a single line of code.

Comment: Indeed, list comprehensions can be powerful. Happy coding :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
def data():
data = [['a','c','g'],['t','g','c']]
dictionaries = [{'a':1,'c':2,'g':3,'t':4},{'a':3,'c':1,'g':2,'t':4},{'a':2,'c':3,'g':4,'t':1}]

result = []
for row in range(0, len(data)):
    temp = [0]* len(data[0])
    for col in range(0, len(data[0])):
        temp[col] = (dictionaries[col])[data[row][col]]
    result.append(temp)
print result
```

traverse through the 2D array using row, col. use the col loop variable to get the required dictionary and get the data value by using both row and col.